# Cannot obtain a normalised eigenfunction for a boundary problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I have done most of the problem, but I cannot solve the part where I have to do an integration.

The problem says:

"Determine the normalised eigenfunctions of the boundary problem $y''+\lambda y=0$, $y'(0)=0$, $y(1)+y'(1)=0$. Expand the function $f(x)=x, 0\le x<1$ in terms of these normalised eigenfunctions."

So well, what I have done so far and is the same as the results given by the professor is:

I have a characteristic equation $r^2+\lambda=0$, so $r=\pm\sqrt{-\lambda}$.

If $\lambda=-\mu^2$, where $\mu>0$, then $r=\pm\mu$ and $y(x)=c_1 e^{\mu x}+c_2 e^{-\mu x}$. So I get that there is no non-trivial solution, only the trivial one $c_1=c_2=0$.

If $\lambda=0$, $r=0$ and $y(x)=c_1 x+c_2$. From this I get that we also only have the trivial solution $c_1=c_2=0$.

If $\lambda=\mu^2$, where $\mu>0$. Then $r=\pm i\mu$ and $y(x)=c_1 \cos(\mu x)+c_2 \sin(\mu x)$. From this I get the eigenfunctions $\phi_n(x)=c_n \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$ for $\lambda_n=\mu_n^2$.

**So here is where I get things wrong**

To obtain the normalised eigenfunctions we need to compute the "length" of the eigenfunctions. So

$$1=c_n^2 \int_0^1 \cos^2(\sqrt{\lambda_n} x)dx$$

However, the result for this that is given by the professor is
$$1=c_n^2\left(\frac{1+\sin^2(\sqrt{\lambda_n})}{2}\right)$$

But what I get is $$1=\frac{c_n^2}{4}\left(\frac{\sin(2\sqrt{\lambda_n})}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}+2\right)$$
But since $c_n$ is a constant dependant on n, I guess this can also be expressed as

$$1=\frac{c_n^2}{4}\left(\sin(2\sqrt{\lambda_n})+2\right)$$

But I still cannot get the correct result :/

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [**here**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BCos%5BSqrt%5BL%5D%20x%5D%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) you dealt well with the double-angle substitution and, hence, you obtained the correct result for the integral. I can't see how your teacher get to that result, not even substituting $\sin{2 \mu_n} = 2 \sin{\mu_n}\cos{\mu_n}$.

Furthermore, notice that your ODE is homogenous and hence the constant of integration is not worth to be retained so you could define:

> $$y_n(x) = \cos{\mu_n x}, \quad \mu_n = \sqrt{\lambda_n} \tag{1}$$

as the solution of the problem $y_n'' + \lambda_n y_n = 0$, with the corresponding boundary conditions and $\mu_n$ satisfying the trascendental equation:

> $$\frac{1}{\mu_n} = \tan{\mu_n}. \tag{2}$$

Then, $\mu_n$ are your eigenvalues, with associated eigenfunctions $y_n(x)$.

Regarding the expansion of $f$ in terms of the eigenfunctions $\phi_n$, you would have:

> $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n P_n(x), \quad f_n \in \mathbb{R}. \tag{3}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\omega(x) \phi_m(x)$, $\omega(x) = 1$ being the weight function of the problem $\mathcal{L}[y] = - \lambda \omega$, integrating over $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and assumming uniform convergence of the series, we come up with:

> $$ \int^1_0 f \phi_m \, \mathrm{d}x = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \int^1_0 f_n \phi_n \phi_m \, \mathrm{d}x, \tag{4} $$

which after using the property of orthogonality of the eigenfunctions yields:

> $$ \color{blue}{f_n =  \frac{\int^1_0 f(x) \, \phi_n(x)\, \mathrm{d}x}{\int^1_0 \phi^2_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x}  = \frac{\langle f,\phi_n \rangle}{\langle \phi_n, \phi_n \rangle}}, \tag{5} $$

where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is the dot product defined by $\phi_n$ and $\omega$.

Let me know your pogress about this problem.

Cheers!